# Hibernate: Object deleted but still can be loaded by Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

It seems absurd how even after I deleted the object I can load it and print its Id. here's the class that I use to retrieve data from Prof entity :

```
public class ProfCrud {
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session ; 

 public ArrayList<Object> findProfByProfId( int id){
     session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findProfByProfId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
public void deleteProfByProfId(int id){
    ProfCrud pc= new ProfCrud();

            session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();     
        Prof c = (Prof) pc.findProfByProfId(id).get(0);
                session.delete(c);
            transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }   

    System.out.println(((Prof) pc.findProfByProfId(id).get(0)).getId());
}
```

}

Comment: Does your outer scope (the scope where you are printing the prof's ID) have a transaction?  Is it possible you are seeing the results of repeatable read isolation?

Comment: I don't think it's the case, I tried to print it out side the method and it gives a result anyway.

Comment: And outside the method is outside any outer transaction or session correct?  Where is the session used by findProfByProfId created?

Comment: @Pace I don't know, I edited the post and added the whole class if you could help

Comment: It looks like you're opening the session twice at the beginning of the deleteProfByProfId method, If you remove one of the open session calls does that make the problem go away?

Comment: even after deleting one of the session call I have the same problem !! I solved the problem by the answer below, I know it's not good but I don't have other choice !

Answer (score 0):

just before the print I opened a session, started a transaction and closed it. Now I can't load the object. I don't know why but it worked if any one could clarify it more I'll be thankful.

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();     
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
```